# Creating a Requirements Traceability Matrix

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am having some trouble creating a traceability matrix similar to the image shown below.

How would I be able to create:

- Rotated column headings
- Heading row height different to the other rows

any advice is much appreciated

[image]

Here's my attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{lllll} 
    \toprule 
     Requirements & Accuracy & Coverage & Scalability & Infrastructure  \\ 
    \midrule 
    Inertial Navigation & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark & \\
    RFID & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark & \\
    Bluetooth & & \checkmark  & & \checkmark\\
    WLAN & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & \checkmark \\
    Infrared & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & \checkmark\\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide what you have so far. You should be able to provide the tabular code in a complete, compilable document but with non-rotated headers, for instance. Then people just need to adjust it. Don't worry if it goes off the page.

Comment: `makecell` is a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: rotated heads]

This combines `makecell` with the `booktabs` style you are already using which, as you know, is allergic to vertical rules (so I assume you don't want those).

Note that I'm a great fan of TikZ but using a `tikzpicture` for each tick is surely overkill if anything is. Even if you need TikZ elsewhere in the document, please don't use it here!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amssymb,makecell,rotating}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\theadfont{\bfseries}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Infrastructure}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule
     \thead{Requirements} & \rothead{Accuracy} & \rothead{Coverage} & \rothead{Scalability} & \rothead{Infrastructure}  \\
    \midrule
    Inertial Navigation & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ & \\
    RFID & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$  & $\checkmark$ & \\
    Bluetooth & & $\checkmark$  & & $\checkmark$\\
    WLAN & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$  & & $\checkmark$ \\
    Infrared & $\checkmark$ & $\checkmark$  & & $\checkmark$\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```